# How can you do named parameters with a default value for closures

Tags: groovy

So basically I would like to do something like this:

```
execute = { String param1, String param2 = 'default' ->
    echo "${param1}"
    echo "${param2}"
}

execute(
    param1: 'Test1',
    param2: '123'
)
execute('Test2')
```

But that doesn't work, as it puts all the given parameters in `param1`. It would be possible with a map, but I would like to keep the functionality of default parameters.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Also, I am new to groovy, so this might already been asked - if so, I would appreciate a pointer in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy has no named arguments.  You can only allow a map and make it
look it would.  So you have to allow for the map and deal with the
fall-back yourself.  E.g. merge the incoming map with some default map
or pick the defaults where you need them.  E.g.

```
def c = { Map args=[:] ->
    def param1 = args.param1 ?: 'fallback'
    println param1
}

c()
// ⇒ fallback
c(param1: "set")
// ⇒ set
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunate that it doesn't exist, but at least I know now!

Comment: Groovy has no [named arguments](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_named_parameters)?

Comment: @jaco0646 Yes, groovy has no named arguments. If you want to see how this works in other languages have a look at e.g. Kotlin. The docs are wrong - this is passing maps.